# sed command is failing to delete a line in file

Tags: shell, sed

My file contains below lines

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
```

when 5 processes are running simultaneously and deleting one line each in the above file using `sed` command, some times lines are not getting deleted.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: How are you invoking `sed` to run in parallel 5 times? Using `parallel` command?

Comment: sed command is in a script and I'm running that script in 5 sessions.

Comment: Concurrent file access may be tricky, is there absolutely no way around it? Use a locking mechanism for each invocation's sed access to the file.

Comment: BTW, what is your requirement? You don't need to do this in multiple sessions!

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, sed does not fail but concurrent access giving you problem. Here is the scenario (i guess).

- session A and B try to run your sed command.
- A read the file
- B read the file
- A done and write the file
- B write the file

Result : changes by A is lost.

What you should do? use some lock to protect concurrent access. You can use the [flock](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html) command.

```
 (
     flock -n 9 || exit 1
     # Your 'sed' command if script can access file
 ) 9>/var/lock/mylockfile
```